# How do I move on to the next string in my vector?

Tags: c++, loops, iterator

```
for(listOfStringsIterator = listOfStrings.begin(); listOfStringsIterator != listOfStrings.end(); listOfStringsIterator++) {
    string finalstring = listOfStrings.front();
    string kmerStrings;
    for(int a = 0; a < finalstring.length(); a++) {
        if(finalstring[a+2] == NULL){
            string nextLine = listofStrings.at(listofStrings.front() + 1);
            kmerStrings = string() + finalstring[a] + finalstring[]
                std::cout << nextLine << std::endl;
        }
        else{
            kmerStrings = string() + finalstring[a] + finalstring[a+1] + finalstring[a+2];
            std::cout << kmerStrings << std::endl;
        }
```

I'm trying to move on to the string after the one i'm currently on after I don't have enough chars to create a 3 letter sequence.

Comment: What about [continue](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/continue)?

Comment: What is the point of the iterator?

Comment: @Galik I wanted to get the first chars in the next statement though.

Comment: @GabrielVasconcelos   The iterator is to move through lines in my textfile one at a time..

Comment: But you don't use it inside your loop at all. You'll always read the same line, the `front()` in your list.

Comment: Also, looping with iterators is not the preferred way of doing it. You should either iterate it with an `int i`-`list[i]` loop or a ranged loop `for (auto& element : list)`.